# Is it possible to find back my forgetten password if I can login via key?

Tags: password

I am using a ssh key to login a remote server but today I want to login with username and key pair.

I can still get on server with my key but I can't remember the password. Is it possible to get it back or just change it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you are a standard, non-root user, the answer is **no**, you can't reset your **unknow** password. The reason is to prevent someone accessing your unattended keyboard to change your password.

nowdays your password is stored in a file call /etc/shadow which format look like

```
archemar:$6$wmG27ByC$Aig4Uo(abridged)CXCMbkXEAbJ6q3vyCsdIFd27lA6r.:16491:0:99999:7:::
```

and you can't guess your password from `Aig4Uo(abridged)CXCMbkXEAbJ6q3vyCsdIFd27lA6r.`